# WishList Member wishlistmember_shoppingcart_register (action)

Tags: php, wordpress, api

I'm new to Wordpress plugin development but I've decided to build one in order to internally connect to the WishList Member (WLM) API.

I want to capture the user's sign-up information every time they register using the WLM checkout form on our website. The WLM tech support suggested I use the wishlistmember_shoppingcart_register hook in their API. They also said information about the registration can be found in the $_POST variable.

Since I'm so new to Wordpress Plugin development I'm not really sure how to implement the hook. I've learned how to use the WLM API's main functions from the code they provided but that's all I can figure out.

How does the hook get triggered every time the user is added? Should I use a shortcode on the page with the WLM form? How do I access the $_POST variable in my plugin?

Also, I've noticed some Wordpress plugins are just series of function calls and others create a class object. Can I use either approach in my plugin?

A little guidance would be appretiated.

Thanks
Mike

UPDATE: Here's the code I've been working on...

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: MGC
Description: A plugin to integrate with WLM
Author: Mike Grossman
Version: 0.1
*/

require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/wlmapiclass.php');

//echo "<h1>Hello world!</h1>";

$member_registration_results = array();

add_action('admin_menu', 'mgc_plugin_setup_menu'); //load menu bar on the admin panela and run the function 

function mgc_plugin_setup_menu(){
        add_menu_page( 'MGC Plugin Page', 'MGC Plugin', 'manage_options', 'mgc-plugin', 'dp_api_internal' ); 
}

function mgc_init(){
        echo "<h1>Hello World!</h1>";
}

function dp_api_internal(){

    if (function_exists('wlmapi_get_levels')){
        $levels = wlmapi_get_levels();

        print_r($levels);
    }
}

 function dp_api_external(){

     //No external connection needed

}

function member_registration() {

            $test_member_data = array(
                "user_login" => 'test_wlmtest_member',
                "user_email" => 'test_member@wlmtest.com',
                "first_name" => 'Test First Name',
                "last_name" => 'Test Last Name',
                "display_name"=>'Test Display Name',
                "user_pass" => '1234567890',
                "Sequential"=> true,
                "SendMail" => 'true',
                "Levels" => array($_POST['wlmtest_level_id'])
            );

            if (isset($_POST['wlmtest_action'] ) && $_POST['wlmtest_action']=="member_registration_internal_api" ) {
                /* Test Member Registration Using Internal API */
                $this->member_registration_results['internal']  = $this->RegisterMemberInternalAPI($test_member_data);
            }
}

function RegisterMemberInternalAPI ($member_data) {
            $response =  wlmapi_add_member($member_data);
            return $response;
}



?>
```

I found all of the WLM code in tutorials and free 3D party plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out how to get the WLM member data I wanted without using the API. I captured the WLM shortcodes (i.e. [wlm_lastname]) after the user has registered on the website. Also, the plugin I created didn't need a Wordpress admin panel so I removed that code as well.